# Actions on a collection (sorting, limiting, searching, etc.)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

Normally when I use jquery to build a simple app to show data, I would simply change some global variables depending on certain actions and then when I was ready to retrieve data from the server, I'd pass those vars along to the server.

What is a good way to do this in backbone.js? Does my view handle that? I have this view so far:

```
var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },  

    render: function() {

    template = _.template("\
    <table>\
    <% _(collection).each(function(model){%>\
    <tr><td><%=model.name%></td><td><%=model.email%></td></tr>\
    <%}); %>\
    </table>\
    ");

        var context = {collection: this.collection.toJSON()};
        $(this.el).html(template(context));
        $('#app').html(this.el);
    }
});
```

Basically in my controller I create a `users` collection and then I use `users.fetch()` and then pass the `users` collection to a new `ListView` object. The initialize function automatically renders (is this bad practice?) I know there's events in backbone.js, and I'm guessing that's where this needs to end up. How do I handle sorting by certain fields or searching for certain text in certain fields or choosing how many results come back (i.e. 10 per page), etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Since backbone.js uses a RESTfull Api it's not so easy. You would have to override the Backbone.sync READ method to construct your own URL call: [How to override Backbone.sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096549/how-to-override-backbone-sync)

This might help you as well: [REST API Best practices: Where to put parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024271/rest-api-best-practices-where-to-put-parameters)

I would render then, when you have gotten back the data you need. Initialize will be called on var listview = new ListView(), and if you don't have the data bootstrapped - probably nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use set the comparator like this:

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-comparator

```
var Chapter  = Backbone.Model;
var chapters = new Backbone.Collection;

chapters.comparator = function(chapter) {
  return chapter.get("page");
};

chapters.add(new Chapter({page: 9, title: "The End"}));
chapters.add(new Chapter({page: 5, title: "The Middle"}));
chapters.add(new Chapter({page: 1, title: "The Beginning"}));

alert(chapters.pluck('title'));
```

you can use Collection.sort()

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-sort

or you can use Underscore methods and manually reset the collection
http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-Underscore-Methods

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-reset