# rewrite backbone.sync

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, coffeescript, socket.io

I'm using backbone.js with websockets and sending data to the server based on events.

Is it possible to design/rewrite Backbone.sync to transport model changes to the server in a normalized way?

Any general examples of this would be great, then I can figure out how to integrate it with my server-side methods.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would start with the [documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync) and the [annotated source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-136) for the Backbone.Sync function.

Then, see how the ["local storage"](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone-localstorage.html) module modifies Backbone.Sync to store locally instead of to the server as an example of overriding behavior.

Perhaps, this [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096549/how-to-override-backbone-sync) will also help.

Answer (score 8):

Backbone.Sync has very little code, and it's common to re-write it to work the way you need. I would start by reading the [annotated code](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-136), and then there are [several](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage) [plugins](https://github.com/logicalparadox/backbone.iobind) that you can look at for examples of how to rewrite it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is module called backbone.io, try `npm install backbone.io`