# What is the least ugly way to force Backbone.sync updates to use POST instead of PUT?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Some of my Backbone models should always use POST, instead of POST for create and PUT for update.  The server I persist these models to is capable of supporting all other verbs, so using `Backbone.emulateHTTP` is not a perfect solution either.

Currently I override the `isNew` method for these models and have it return `true`, but this is not ideal.

Other than modifying the backbone.js code directly, is there a simple way to achieve this goal on a model-by-model basis?  Some of my models can use PUT (they are persisted to a different server that supports all verbs, including PUT), so replacing Backbone.sync with one that converts the 'update' method to 'create' is not ideal either.

Comment: You can declare a `sync` method for your models that need POST instead of PUT and implement it locally on your models that way. You don't have to overwrite it for all models. Take a look at this answer on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5096624/844726

Comment: Isn't this what [`Backbone.emulateHTTP`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync-emulateHTTP) is for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add a sync(method, model, [options]) directly to your models you need to override.

```
YourModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  sync: function(method, model, options) {
    //perform the ajax call stuff
  }
}
```

Here's some more information: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync

Answer (score 56):

For anyone who needs to force a POST/PUT request on the instance directly:

```
thing = new ModelThing({ id: 1 });
thing.save({}, { // options
    type: 'post' // or put, whatever you need
})
```

Comment: While the accepted answer works and is versatile, I think this is the more appropriate answer to the question.

Answer (score 15):

Short and Sweet is put this on Top

```
Backbone.emulateHTTP = true;
```

This will use Get for Pull and Post for All pushes (read Create, Update, Delete)

Answer (score 5):

the way I've done it is to override `sync()` thusly

```
Models.Thing = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.url = "/api/thing/" + this.id;
    },
    sync: function(method, model, options) {
        if (method === "read") method = "create";    // turns GET into POST
        return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
    },
    defaults: {
        ...
```

Answer (score 4):

I used a modification of Andres' answer and instead of havivng to remember to pass the option `{ type: 'post' }` everywhere that I call `.save()` I instead just replaced the `save` function on the model to have it always add that option then call the base implementation. It felt cleaner...

```
module.exports = Backbone.Model.extend({
  idAttribute: 'identifier',
  urlRoot: config.publicEndpoint,

  save: function (attributes, options) {
    // because the 'identifier' field is filled in by the user, Backbone thinks this model is never new. This causes it to always 'put' instead of 'post' on save.
    // overriding save here to always pass the option use post as the HTTP action.
    options = _.extend(options || {}, { type: 'post' });
    return Backbone.Model.prototype.save.call(this, attributes, options);
  }
});
```