# Backbone model.save() is sending PUT instead of POST

Tags: javascript, http, backbone.js

I call save using this:

```
console.log(this.model.isNew());
console.log(this.model);

this.model.save({}, {
    success: function (model, response, options) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (model, xhr, options) {
        console.log(xhr.result.Errors);
    }   
});
```

The `isNew()` returns false. But the output of `this.model` has an ID of 0. (this.model.id is 0 as well)

My url is `url: ROOTAREA + "/Expenses/Entry/",`

Updating works fine, and uses PUT as expected.

Edit : here's part of my model:

```
   defaults: function () {
        return {
            DocumentDate: "",
            JobNo_: "",
            PhaseCode: "",
            WorkTypeCode: "",
            Description: "",
            Quantity: 0,
            UnitCost: 0,
            ExpenseCurrencyCode: "",
            ReimbursementCurrencyCode: "",
            UnitofMeasureCode: "DIEM",
            LineNo_: 0
        };
    },
    idAttribute: "LineNo_",
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

ID should not even exist for a new entry.
The issue is in the part you didn't show - in the part where you instantiate, create and populate the model.

Here is a quote from [the Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-isNew):

> If the model does not yet have an `id`, it is considered to be new.

It is clear from your code that you are assigning an id attribute.
Your backend should be doing that.
And since you are doing it on a client, backbone presumes it it not new, and uses `PUT`

Comment: I've made an edit to my post showing the model. Should I change LineNo_ to something other than 0?

Comment: @Rail24 Remove it completely, if you can. Backbone checks the id against null to determine if it's new. See http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-63

Comment: I changed LineNo_ to default as null and it solved my problem! Thank you toninoj!

Comment: The timer <_< I will in a minute.

Comment: Why it's marked as accepted answer? It's more confusing than helpful. The correct answer is The latest (by @seppestaes)

Answer (score 20):

The above answers are correct in that if the `model` you are `.save`'ing has an `id` attribute backbone will do a `PUT` rather than a `POST`.

This behavior can be overridden simply by adding `type: 'POST'` to your save block:

```
var fooModel = new Backbone.Model({ id: 1});

fooModel.save(null, {
  type: 'POST'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, it helped me in a similar case.

I found out (reading the Backbone source) that you don't need to create the model, save it and then add to the collection, you just have to pass type:'POST' to the collection's create() method:

fooCollection.create({id: 1}, {type:'POST'});

Comment: For other solutions see: [What is the least ugly way to force Backbone.sync updates to use POST instead of PUT?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8527694/1218980)

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the ID in defaults, just make sure it's set to `null` (isNew will be set to true).

In your case it must be

```
LineNo_: null
```