# Backbone trying a put instead of a post

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

For some odd reason, Backbone is trying to put my model object instead of posting it to the server.

The error is an HTTP 500 error because Backbone is trying to put a model with no id (because I have made it undefined):

```
 PUT /api/teams/undefined 500 285ms - 135b
```

Here's my code:

```
this.model.id = undefined;
this.model._id = undefined;
teamCollection.add(this.model);
this.model.save(null,
    {
        success: function (model) {

            $('.top-right').notify({
                message: {text: ' New team added!  '},
                type: 'info',
                fadeOut: {
                    delay: 3500
                }
            }).show();
            window.userHomeMainTableView.render();
        }
        ,
        error: function (model) {
            teamCollection.remove(model);
            $('.top-right').notify({
                message: {text: ' Error adding team :(  '},
                type: 'danger',
                fadeOut: {
                    delay: 3500
                }
            }).show();
        }
    });
```

even after "forcing" the model.id and model._id to be undefined, Backbone still tries to do an HTTP PUT. How can this be?

Answer (score 3):

The syncing process internally uses [`Model#isNew`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-isNew) to decide if it should PUT or POST. `isNew` is very simple minded:

> **isNew** `model.isNew()`
>
> [...] If the model does not yet have an `id`, it is considered to be new.

and that [check is done using](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.1.2/backbone.js#L553):

```
!this.has(this.idAttribute)
```

The [`has` method](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.1.2/backbone.js#L301) is just a simple wrapper around `attr`:

```
has: function(attr) {
  return this.get(attr) != null;
}
```

so these are irrelevant:

```
this.model.id = undefined;
this.model._id = undefined;
```

when Backbone is deciding to PUT or POST, those don't really remove the `id` attribute, they break your model.

I think you'd be better off copying the model (without the `id`) and saving the copy:

```
var data = m.toJSON();
delete data.id;
var copy = new Model(data);
```

Or better, create a whole new model, populate it with data, and then save the new model instance.

I think you'd need to [`unset`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-unset) the `id` attribute and manually remove the `id` property to make what you're trying to do work.

Comment: well, I defined my idAttribute in my model as _id, so setting _id should affect it, right

Comment: If you have an `idAttribute: '_id'` then you'd want to `m.unset('_id')` and `delete m.id`. But still, what you're trying to do looks a bit odd to me, it looks like you're trying to re-use an existing model instance when you should be creating a new one.

Comment: nope, I am sending a new model object to the new view instance, that's why it's so beffuddling

Comment: If it is a new model then why does it have an `id`? The `id` is supposed to come from the server when you save the new model.

Comment: `var copy = new Model(_.omit(m.attributes, m.idAttribute));` would avoid using `toJSON` and the need to delete the id.

Answer (score 1):

that's strange it looks like it should do a POST from your code. It looks like you can ovverride it though. From the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384448/backbone-model-save-is-sending-put-instead-of-post) here

```
fooModel.save(null, {
  type: 'POST'
});
```

Comment: yes, thanks, I saw that, but in general I don't want to force things, there has to be a good reason why this is happening.

Answer (score -1):

use the following code snippet to set the id to undefined.

```
this.model.set('id',undefined');
```

although if it's a new model you don't need to do this. it will be undefined by default.
if you have used the idAttribute for defining the model and say it's value is userId then you need to do something like this.

```
this.model.set('userId',undefined');
```