# how to unset an _id backbone model attribute?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model

I would like to `unset()` the `_id` attribute from an instance of a model, **to make a `POST` request using the `save()` model method**.

But i get a `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'call' backbone-min.js` because of this line:

```
myModel.unset('_id');
```

I am using `idAttribute: "_id"` so i tried:

```
myModel.unset('id');
```

But it doesn't unset the `_id` attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force a POST request when saving a model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41090399/how-to-force-a-post-request-when-saving-a-model)

Comment: Don't unset the `_id` attribute or `id` property to make a POST request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the least ugly way to force Backbone.sync updates to use POST instead of PUT?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8527694/1218980)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `model.unset('_id')` should work fine. My guess is that the error is thrown by a `change` event listener, either in your code or some library code. In order to not trigger events you can use the `silent:true` option.

However, if you simply want to force the `model.save()` method to perform a `POST`, you  don't need to unset the `_id` attribute.

Instead override the [`model.isNew`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-isNew) method. Backbone uses this to determine whether a model is new (and should be `POST`ed) or existing (and should be `PUT`). Overriding the method to always return true will make your model to be `POST`ed every time:

```
isNew: function() { return true; }
```

Comment: Careful with this one, from now on the model you set that as will always be new, no matter what.  I you ever want to do a `PUT` it will require applying the old behavior.

Comment: A little late, but I'm with Joe on this. Don't override `isNew` to force a POST request. [Here's 4 alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41091957/1218980).

Answer (score 0):

Backbone stores the attributes in an object called `attributes` within the model. The attribute `_id`, although representative of the ID of that model is not what is used to determine whether a model is new.

There is a *property* called `id` (sibling of `attributes`) which is what is used to make the `isNew()` determination.

If you want to force a `POST`, you'll need to delete the `id` property:

```
var id = model.id;
model.unset('_id');
delete model.id;
model.save(); // this will do a POST
```

Comment: I don't believe this is entirely accurate. Backbone does use the `model.id` field to determine if the model `isNew`, but using `unset` will make a `set` call that will clear the `id` when the `idAttribute` is cleared. See http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-45.

Comment: @dule Backbone does indeed use `model.id` to do an `isNew` check -- which is what I said in my second paragraph. I was merely trying to clarify that `model.id` is different from `model.attributes.id` (which is what the getters use).