# Backbone save() method Post insead of Put

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to update data on backbone.But my save() function post insead of put.

```
editEvent:function(e){
         var departments=new Department();
       departments.set("departmentName",this.$el.find(".departmentName").val());
            departments.save();

            this.render();

        },
```

departmentModel

```
    var Department = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "/rest/department",
    idAttribute:'departmentID'

    }
});
return Department;
```

template

```
    <th>
    <span>{{user.department.departmentName}}</span>
    <input data-placement="top" title="Boş geçilemez!" class="form-control text-center departmentName" type='text'
           style='display: none;'  value='{{user.department.departmentName}}'/>
</th>
```

Comment: I wrote an [extensive answer on how to force a POST request with Backbone](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41091957/1218980). Most technique could be used to force a PUT request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's by design, here's a snippet from the [Backbone docs for the `save` function](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save):

> If the model [`isNew`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-isNew), the save will be a `"create"` (HTTP `POST`), if the 
>   model already exists on the server, the save will be an "update" (HTTP
>   `PUT`).

Model is considered 'New' if it does not have an `id`.

Since you're creating the model for the first time, Backbone will use the `POST` method as it should, because it means you're creating a new resource. For more info on the [meaning of HTTP verbs](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html).

My suggestion would be solving this on the server side and making separate handlers for POST and PUT, but if you really want to force PUT method, here are some tips: [What is the least ugly way to force Backbone.sync updates to use POST instead of PUT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527694/what-is-the-least-ugly-way-to-force-backbone-sync-updates-to-use-post-instead-of)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with using id.If you try PUT request without id,backbone think "it's a new model".But you save with data's id value, backbone think PUT request.

That's why i tried put request with id and that's worked.

```
departments.set("departmentID",this.$el.find(".departmentName").data("id"));
          departments.set("departmentName",this.$el.find(".departmentName").val());
          departments.save();
```

Comment: That's what [Mario's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43582132/1218980) is about. You should upvote and accept his.