# How to call parent backbone sync method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In my application I override Backbone.sync as follows:

```
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options){ 
    //Some custom code

    //THIS FAILS.
    Backbone.prototype.sync.call(this, method, model, options); 
}}
```

My question is, how do I call the original sync method?  Do I need to use this.sync instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this, might not be the best solutions but it works:

```
var parentSyncMethod = Backbone.sync; //save parent method, the override
Backbone.sync = function() {
    // Your code here.
    var parentSyncMethod.apply(Backbone, arguments);
};
```

Hope it helps in some way

Answer (score 9):

From what I understand, Backbone.sync checks to see if there is a locally defined version of sync and calls that before calling the global Backbone.sync :

```
(this.sync || Backbone.sync)
```

So, given that your Model is something like TestModel. I think you can do something like this (forgive, me this might not be the correct syntax, javascript is far from my specialty):

```
var TestModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ 

    "sync": function(method, model, options) { 
        //Some custom code

        Backbone.sync(method, model, options); 
    }
});
```

This is what I've gathered from [here](http://backbonefu.com/2011/11/modifying-your-urls-on-the-fly-using-the-request-method-with-sync-in-backbone-js/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5096624/242426)

Comment: I've used this approach before and found that it works well, especially if you need a model-specific sync. Altering Backbone.sync directly (as shown in another answer) will affect all of the models, which may not be what you need.

Answer (score 4):

```
var TestModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
    sync: function(method, model, options){  
        // some code here
        return Backbone.sync(method, model, options); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`Backbone.prototype.sync.call` won't work because `sync` is not defined on the prototype. Inspect the `Backbone` object in the console to see its structure. You'll want to either name your own method something else or save a reference to the original `sync` method before you override it with your own implementation.