# Backbone.js sync using post variables, not json

Tags: json, backbone.js

I'm new to backbone and trying to write an html5 front end for an existing (and pretty big) REST back end. I found that when saving a model, backbone by default sends the model encoded as JSON which my existing API doesn't support.
Is it possible to send plain simple post request with variables using backbone?

Comment: duplicated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096549/how-to-override-backbone-sync

Comment: It's duplicated, but phrased very differently, so if the poster searched for their own problem, they wouldn't necessarily find the answer. It actually points to a big problem with technical searches - if you don't use the right terms, you won't find an easily found resource (so then it's not easily findable for you).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `Backbone.emulateJSON = true`

copied from the [official documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync-emulateJSON):

> If you're working with a legacy web server that can't handle requests
>   encoded as application/json, setting Backbone.emulateJSON = true; will
>   cause the JSON to be serialized under a `model` parameter, and the
>   request to be made with a application/x-www-form-urlencoded mime type,
>   as if from an HTML form.

Comment: This is still not really using what I think of as post variables. It's stuffing a JSON object into a "model" variable..