# Send API key with json when model is synching

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am implementing a project which uses backbone.js on the browser to communicate with my server. Is it possible to send the api key with the request without adding it in the model? and on response can I check for data that has nothing to do with the actual model, for example an access token?

Thank you.

Comment: where do you want to append the Api key to?

Comment: Preferably appended to the json being sent.

Comment: I recently answered this question in another SO thread, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547498/how-to-override-backbone-sync-so-it-adds-the-apikey-and-username-at-the-end and see if that gets you on your way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to override Backbone.sync so it adds the apikey and username at the end?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547498/how-to-override-backbone-sync-so-it-adds-the-apikey-and-username-at-the-end)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started

```
//the api key object
var apikey = {api:"^@%&HJJHJSDNkkjGHGSd*^*JHJ"};

//Backbone model
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
url:"/todo",
sync:function(method,model,options){
  _.extend(model.attributes,apikey);
  Backbone.sync(method,model,options);
}});
```

#### Update

```
//the api key object
var apikey = {api:"^@%&HJJHJSDNkkjGHGSd*^*JHJ"};

//Backbone model
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
url:"/todo",
sync:function(method,model,options){
    $.ajaxSetup({headers:apikey});
    Backbone.sync(method,model,options);
}});

var x = new model({todo:"Welcome"}).save();
​
```

after some thinking it doesn't make sense to send 'munched' model to the service hence the updated code will attach apikey with the request headers. Key to search for in request headers is **api**

Comment: Do you really intend to add `api` to the model's attributes?

Comment: @muistooshort I was surprised by that requirement too(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633338/send-api-key-with-json-when-model-is-synching/10633763#comment13783373_10633338) only json being sent is through the model. But i should recommend HttpHeaders which is standard being used now

Comment: The problem is that `_.extend` modifies its first argument, overriding `Backbone.sync` should allow you to add `api` to the JSON without changing the model's attributes behind everyone's back.

Comment: @muistooshort What can you now say about the updated code, waiting for your feedback

Comment: Yeah, I `headers` is better. You might be able to add the API key to the model's `url` as well (depends on the remove service's requirements of course).

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. But I wanted to append it through json. I will be posting how I did it.

Comment: Since the project evolved, I needed to do more then just pass the api key. So I went to a very similar implemetnation that @Deeptechtons suggested. But instead of extending the model I override   "Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) { }"

Answer (score 3):

Since the api key has to be added nearly in all ajax requests. I used jquery function that is called every time a ajax call is sent:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR){ 
  var newObject = {
     append_new : 'APIKey'
  }

  options.data = $.param($.extend(originalOptions.data, newObject));
});
```

And for the reply part I used:

```
$('body').ajaxSuccess(function(e, xhr, settings){
  console.log(xhr);
});
```