# Backbone pass API key with get/post requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I need to pass an API key every time I want to save my models/collection or make any type of request. Is this possible with jquery or backbone?

Comment: does this thread answer your Q?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547498/how-to-override-backbone-sync-so-it-adds-the-apikey-and-username-at-the-end

Comment: The answer to the question @Emile linked is perfect for addressing this question.  I'd recommend the `ajaxSend` approach, because it lets you deal with the API key in one place and have it handle every AJAX request you make afterwords, without any extra effort.  Also you *could* override Backbone sync, but then any non-Backbone AJAX requests you make won't get the key.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can send it the header. I do this:

```
                this.model.save(attrs, 
                                {
                                headers: {api_key:that.api_key},
                                success: function() {

                                    },
                                    error:   function(model, xhr, options){

                                    },
                                });
```

Comment: This approach works, but it requires a lot of code duplication since you need it for every `save` (or `destroy`) call you make.  By using `Backbone.sync` (or better yet by using jQuery's `$.ajaxSend` function) you can handle the whole API key issue in a single place.

Answer (score -1):

use $.ajaxSetup:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('api_key', api_key);
  }
});
```

wrap this into a function and run it on every page(if you have multiple pages). if it is a single page app, just run it when backbone loads.

you can define the api key some where (put it on the window object, or hide it in your DOM), or pass it to this function as a parameter.

Comment: whoever down-voted this, could you provide some explanation so I can improve the answer?