# backbone model fetch - mock back-end

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I have a model and I am trying to fetch it using `model.fetch();`. The model's urlRoot set to the back-end of my application ("/backend/item"), but right now I don't have the back-end environment. So I decided to mock the results. I added a route inside my router:

```
"backend/item/:id": "data_getItem"
```

and a function:

```
data_getItem: function(id) {
  console.log("data_getItem: "+ id);
  return {
    animals: [
      {
        name: 'flying cat',
        type: 'none'
      }
    ]
  };
}
```

When running the application I can see ajax call to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/backend/item/1" but the console is empty and I get an error (the fetch function returns me to the error callback). Why is that? How can I mock the back-end?

> EDIT
>   Actually @rjz helped me with the things I want to do, but I really want to know if an ajax call can be catched by backbone router.
>   My intuition tells me not because ajax call cannot execute backbone client code and therefore the router concept is not relevant. Am I right?..

Comment: You might read over http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096549/how-to-override-backbone-sync

Comment: @rjz: Actually this helped me but I really want to know if an ajax call can get access to route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want to use a `Backbone.Router` to catch your AJAX calls. If your goal is mocking out the backend of your project, you should use a testing framework to do this. A down and dirty way would be to use something like:

- [mock-ajax](https://github.com/mobz/mock-ajax)
- [jquery-mockajax](https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax)

or if you want to do something more like unit testing I would look at [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) and its [AJAX mocking library](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-ajax).

**Update to answer your question:**

The short answer is no, a `Backbone.Router` cannot intercept AJAX calls.

This is because the router works by listening to events that have to do with the URL. Specifically, the router is listening to the `hashchange` or `popstate` events (depending on if you are using `pushState`). Since AJAX calls do no interact with the URL they pretty much totally bypass this system.

Comment: Thanks, but I am asking about the possibility of ajax call to be catched by backbone router. I know this is not optimal or not the way to do it (and I am not going to use it) but I am just asking hypotheticalץ

Comment: Added changes to answer you question. Short answer: No it can't.