# Backbone.js Models and Collections Sync

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone.js with C# REST services, however we have separate endpoints for GETTING and POSTING data back to the server.

Using Backbone, how can we create our own unique save methods?

Answer (score 1):

You need override `Backbone.sync()`.

You can do this globally for your application or specific to your model(s).

The best explanation and pattern I've seen comes from Addy Osmani's *Developing Backbone.js Applications*: http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#backbones-sync-api

The pattern is really nice because you define your persistence API elsewhere, and just assign the methods based on the request and method.

Also, here is really resourceful QA: [How to override Backbone.sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096549/how-to-override-backbone-sync?rq=1)

Have a look at the `Backbone.service` plugin: https://github.com/mkuklis/backbone.service
It allows your to include non-restful endpoints in your model.