# Why Backbone.Collection.fetch get nothing?

Tags: json, backbone.js

I'm new to BackboneJS. I try a demo of it, but messages.fetch() results nothing. And I override the Backbone.sync function to return a json, but messages.length always 0. Here is my code:

```
var Message = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var MessageStore = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Message
});
Backbone.sync = function() {
    return [{"content":"Hi there","id":1},{"content":"How are you?","id":2}];
}
var messages = new MessageStore;
messages.fetch();
console.log(messages.length);          // 0
console.log(JSON.stringify(messages)); // []
```

I don't know where is wrong. Dose the response have to be a certain structure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to override Backbone.sync?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096549/how-to-override-backbone-sync)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Backbone.sync` is used as a transport mechanism for read/write to the server, which can be customized by over-riding it, as described in the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync). By default, `Backbone.sync` returns an `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Typically, `fetch` is an asynchronous call, but you threw that out the window, when you over-rode `Backbone.sync`, now all `fetch` returns is

```
[{"content":"Hi there","id":1},{"content":"How are you?","id":2}];
```

So if you did `console.log(messages.fetch());` you would see the above content, but nothing is changed on the `messages` collection.

Let's pretend we didn't touch `Backbone.sync` for the following example, back on topic. I think you are looking for the [parse](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) method for a `Backbone.Collection`.

```
var Messages = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url:'/someurl',
  parse:function(response) {
    // by default response is returned, but you can manipulate the response here.
    // given your example - we just return the static content - will be set on collection
    return [{"content":"Hi there","id":1},{"content":"How are you?","id":2}];
  }
});

//instantiate the new collection
var messages = new Messages();

messages.fetch({
  success:function() {
    console.log(messages.toJSON(),messages.length);
  }
});
```

Remember how I mentioned that `fetch` is asynchronous? When the request is complete, you want to check the results of `fetch` so that's why you need to supply a `success` callback.

You can see this demonstrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c3gBS/).

Comment: asynchronous... that's what i miss! Thanks.