# Backbone Request Payload

Tags: rest, backbone.js

> Hi,
>
> I am a newbie to Backbone, My Rest Server Components Accept Only XML Requests, can Anybody show an example how do i send a xml to a rest api put request.

Comment: Backbone only works with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone uses JSON by default, so to use XML you need to overwrite `Backbone.sync`. Take a look at this answer: [How to override Backbone.sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096549/how-to-override-backbone-sync)

Comment: I did change the options.contentType="application/xml" but still the requestheader contentType is application/json. If somebody can show me an example of sending a xml as a payload that will be very helpful.

Comment: The option you should be using is `dataType`, not `contentType`. See https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I have set dataType also as xml;

Comment: I need to send xml as a payload, anybody please help with an example.

Comment: Oops, sorry: to *send* XML you need to define the `contentType` attribute for the jQuery `$.ajax` call. Once you've serialized your data as XAML in the function call to `ajax` it should send the data as XML correctly. Also, check whether you need to add ".xml" to your url.

Comment: can anybody help me with an example :-(