# Backbone model save with non restful api

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone model like this

```
Report = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: '/reports'
})
```

What I  did:

```
model = new Report({id: 1, name: "Test Report1"});
model.urlRoot = "/reports/" + model.get('id') + "/submit";

model.save(null, {
  patch: true,
  success: function(model, res){
    console.log(res);
  },
  error: function(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

But when I save it I want it to send the request to a path like `/reports/:id/submit` with `patch` but it goes to a path like this `/reports/1/submit/1` with `POST`. What can I do here? Any tweaks? Or should I use `$.ajax` instead?

Comment: Your `urlRoot` property can be passed as `model.urlRoot = "/reports/"` the `id` will get appended automatically.

Comment: Okay, but how do I append `/submit` to `/reports/1` ?

Comment: The `/1` will get auto appended when you set the `urlRoot` as `model.urlRoot = "/reports/"`

Comment: @Kumar Hmm... Is it that you need one URL for fetching **and** a *different* URL for saving?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5096549/2333214

Answer (score 0):

Override `url()` function, not `urlRoot`.

Url is generated in function/parameter `url`.

```
model = new Report({id: 1, name: "Test Report1"});
oldUrl = model.url;
model.url = "/reports/" + model.get('id') + "/submit";

model.save(null, {
  patch: true,
  success: function(model, res){
    console.log(res);
  },
  error: function(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
});

model.url = oldUrl;
```